# How to call a ASP function from onclick in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, session, asp-classic

I have 3 link in my HTML. When I click one of these a variable in the session must change.
How can I do that?

```
<div id="eng">
      <a href="#" onClick="setLanguage('en')";>
           <img id="eng_img" src="bandiera01.png" />
      </a>
 </div>
 <div id="rus">
      <a href="#" onclick="setLanguage('ru');">
           <img id="rus_img" src="bandiera02.png" />
      </a>
 </div>
 <div id="ted">
      <a href="#" onclick="setLanguage('de');">
           <img id="ted_img" src="bandiera03.png" />
      </a>
 </div>
```

setLanguage(txt) is a JavaScript function but I want to use it in ASP to save it in session.

Comment: javascript and asp live in different environments, browser vs server. Be more specific about what you want to acheive

Comment: You don't "call an ASP function" from client-side code.  What you do is make a request to a server-side resource (page) which in this case has ASP code behind it (basically just to run that function, I imagine).  You can use AJAX to make such a request without refreshing the current document.

Comment: is session value can be change through ajax ??

Comment: I have to save the current language of my site. I need to know this variable from every page of my site. I don't know ajax. Can I have a simple example of the code to do that?

Comment: My personal favorite is jquery Post/ get [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/] but have a look at ajax in w3schools [http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Answer (score 1):

You need send the information to server, you can post by a normal link or send by ajax. I think with in this case, is better you send by normal link, for example:

```
<div id="eng">
      <a href="ChangeLanguage.asp?language=en">
           <img id="eng_img" src="bandiera01.png" /></a>
      </a>
 </div>
 <div id="rus">
      <a href="ChangeLanguage.asp?language=ru">
           <img id="rus_img" src="bandiera02.png" />
      </a>
 </div>
 <div id="ted">
      <a href="ChangeLanguage.asp?language=de">
           <img id="ted_img" src="bandiera03.png" />
      </a>
 </div>
```

In the page of destination, you get the "language" information of the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can address this issue in a couple of way:

1. Turn your links into submit buttons, put them inside a form, submit the page server side to manage the language change business logic. This is a classic asp approach. You have to rebuild the page server side.
2. Let the `setLanguage()` fire an ajax call to an asp page that retrieves the localized resources. On success, the resources are mapped into the corresponding elements of the DOM: maybe set this logic into a different function:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="lang">
          <a href="#" data-lang="en">en</a>
     </div>
     <div class="lang">
          <a href="#" data-lang="ru">ru</a>
     </div>
     <div class="lang">
          <a href="#" data-lang="de">de</a>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
    (function($){
        window.setLanguage = function(langCode){
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "myLanguageHandler.asp",
              data: { "languageCode": languageCode },
              async: true,
              error: function (req, status, message) {
                  //manage the error
              },
              success: function (data) {
                  mapPage(data);
              }
            });
            /*
             * for demo purpose only
             * console.log('Set language: ' + langCode);
             */
        };

        $('.lang a').bind('click', function(e){
            window.setLanguage($(e.target).attr('data-lang'));
            return false;
        });
    })(jQuery)
```